# TableViews in iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, uitableview

I am studying TableViews in iOS and Android. For iOS I found an extremely marvelous book called "pro iOS table views", can any one point me to a similar specialized resource with android table views? I already read many android books, My impression and grasping of the material was bad, I am originally a professional C# developer and I know Java well, I think I am supposed to be more android friendly, but the poorly written textbooks that teaches android made the subject harder for me. I prefer to read books.

Comment: Android `ListView` and custom `ListAdapters` are what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some excellent articles on support tablets on Android Developer site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

To support tablet, you are most likely will be using Fragments:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Of course your app would probably need to support 2.x devices, so to use Fragment, which is an Android 3.0 feature you would need to use android support library:
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

The one thing you have to keep in mind is that, while iOS have explicit "phone" version and "tablet" version, Android doesn't really have such a dichotomy. Instead developers are free to decide at which screen size does it make sense to apply "tablet-like" layout for them, depending on the nature of their apps (for example some app may decide to utilize two-pan layout for 5+ inch screens while others would only apply it for 7+ inch screens). This is both empowering and a burden as you as the developer are responsible in making that decision.